# How to select multiple query and retrieve them

Tags: php, mysqli

When I retrieve two tables there's an error. What is the problem with my code? I have no idea how to fix this

```
    <?php
include ('includes/config.php');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_UNAME,DB_PASSWD,DB_NAME);
if(!$mysqli){
  throw new Exception($mysqli->connect_error, $mysqli->connect_errno);
}

$jqry = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time FROM table_time ORDER BY time");
if (!$jqry){

  throw new Exception($mysqli->error);

}
$jqry->execute();
$jqry->bind_result($time);
$jqry->store_result();

$times = array();

while ($jqry->fetch()){

        $times[] = $time;

}
$jqry->close();

$gqry = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT table_group.group FROM table_group.table_group ORDER BY group");
if(!$gqry){

  throw new Exception($gqry->error);
}
$gqry->execute();
$gqry->bind_result($group);
$gqry->store_result();

$groups = array();

while ($gqry->fetch()){

  $groups[] = $group;
}


?>
```

This is the error I got:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\~Jeremiah\system5\joborder.php on line 31
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' in C:\xampp\htdocs\~Jeremiah\system5\joborder.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Comment: what is table_group.table_group ? something does not look correct here.

Comment: Hi thanks For reply..
How to select multiple query using mysqli...
when i select two tables i Got an error.

Comment: You cannot put a table name after the SELECT clause. Answer the questions we have asked in the comments above. Thank you.

Comment: I changed table_group.group to group and the same on first tables
but the error is the same..

Comment: Two errors: Since `time` is a reserved word in MySQL, you need back-ticks for that. So add - ` backticks around time word and remove `$jqry->close();`

Comment: Debug with this: `if(!$gqry){throw new Exception($mysqli->error);}`, note that if `$gqry` is `false`, you must ask the error from the `$mysqli` object, not of a `false` value, which by definition _has no `->error` attribute_.

Comment: @djay; [`time` is not a reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html): _"MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them. Examples are those in the following list:... time ..."_

Comment: @djay: [and `$jqry->close()` is not a problem either](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php).

Comment: @Wrikken `$jqry->close()` in that place is a problem of a bad design (Code smell). That was the point.

Comment: @djay: please explain. Why would closing a statement that exists & works there be a bad design? It certainly has nothing to do with the error the OP gets, the statement is deallocated, and the `$mysqli` connection itself is guaranteed to be ready to handle other requests.

Comment: @Wrikken If I start explaining this, it would be turned into a large discussion about problems of an architecture. - It would be better to implement a `DataMapper` and pass a `$db` as a dependency to the  constructor. I'm so sorry for being non-constructive here.

Comment: @djay: OK, you comment about `->close()` indeed does not matter here. I wonder thoudh: Would you still be opposed to the `->close()` statement inside this 'DataMapper' of yours, and for either yes or no: why is it OK or not OK there?

Comment: @Wrikken There's no point of closing a single connection since PHP automatically does garbage collection. But if for some reason there's a need to do so, it could be placed inside destructor in implementation like this one: http://pastebin.com/rjz8SWJT

Answer (score 0):

your SQL just before the line 31 is invalid. Try executing it against db directly.

from the manual:

```
mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.
```

...and thats why we don't suppress notices in dev enviroment! :)